# How do I know the command that output Total Ether Supply?

Tags: ether

I can see the amount of Ether in https://etherscan.io/stats/supply

More detail can be seen a `pre-sale amount, Mining Block amount, Mining Uncle amount`.

Is there a JSON-RPC or geth command can be seen this?
Even as I see myself surrounded by Ethereum wiki, any community, there is no in sight.

Answer (score 2):

Found [`etherscan-promise`](https://github.com/theblock/etherscan-promise)

> A thin, lightweight promise wrapper for the api.etherscan.io service, http://api.etherscan.io/apis

#### Usage in Node -

```
const etherscan = require('@theblock/etherscan-promise');

// api calls goes here
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but There's no pure rpc-command to be found there. Maybe I don't know so much.

Comment: Yeah, there is no RPC command, May be use can use the api or js.